# Pdf in react-native

Tags: typescript, react-native, pdf, axios, rn-fetch-blob

I'm trying to download a pdf that I receive from an endpoint of an api, when doing the tests via postman and insomnia I receive and can view the PDF file at the same time, but when making this same request, passing the same parameters, in react-native the "data" returns me empty. Can anyone help me?

I'm using a request axios.post waiting for a PDF as a return, but I always get in response an empty "date" and the insomnia I can view and even download the pdf normally